# Page Speed Online vs Chrome Extension

Tags: seo, google, performance, optimization, page-speed

In optimizing a content blog of mine with the goal of achieving the highest page speed score possible for obvious reasons (user experience, SEO, etc..), the results I'm obtaining are throwing me for a loop.

For the sake of completeness, here is **my stack:**

- *CloudFlare DNS + CDN*
- *nginx 1.0.11 stable*
- *PHP-FPM 5.3.6*
- *WordPress latest stable (3.3.1)*
- *WP-Super Cache*

Moving on...

I *originally* was using Page Speed Online to have Google scrape the root URL and see what it turned up, as I assumed that'd be the most accurate representation of the speed it realized when evaluating the website for SEO purposes.  However, the results are... *intriguing* to say the least.  I've **looked at the headers** *extensively* (**sessions, anonymous users, cached vs not-cached, etc..**), yet Page Speed Online seems to report back incorrect results.

After purging every cache that I had and still getting the same funny recommendations by Page Speed Online, I tried out the Chrome extension.  **Here are my findings**:

- **Page Speed Online** reports that I should "*leverage browser caching*" for the majority of my static assets, citing that the *expires* duration on the majority of them is 24h or less, *despite the fact* that I can repeatedly replicate viewing the headers and **seeing that the expires date is correctly set for 1 week** as I have in my nginx configuration.  This applies to .js, .css. png, .jpg, etc....

  - Also, CloudFlare states that it respects any expires headers you have greater than its default 4h, which doesn't seem to be a problem.

- **With** CloudFlare Enabled, **Page Speed Online** reports a score of a **75**, with only 2 medium-priority critiques (one of which is the above caching "*issue*" which isn't actually valid) and one low-priority.  **Without** CloudFlare enabled, I get a score of **88** with *the same* 2 medium-priority reccomendations, but instead 9 low-priority (ex: I was having CloudFlare handle minification of static assets, asynchronously load some of the JavaScript, etc...).

  - Keep in mind this is on a **613MB 32-bit EC2 Micro-Instance** with poor I/O performance and short CPU bursts. Granted, I'm caching a lot of trips to the disk, but an **88** *without* CloudFlare and **75** *with*?

Fast-forward to **Page Speed Chrome Extension**...

- **No cached content, no CloudFlare**: *94*

  - (1 medium-priority, 9 low-priority)

- **Server-side cached page, no CloudFlare**: *95*

  - (0 medium-priority, 9 low-priority)

- **No server-side cached page, *with* CloudFlare)**: *92*

  - (2 medium-priority, 7 low-priority)

- **Server-side cached page, *with* CloudFlare)**: *96*

  - (0 medium-priority, 7 low-priority)

Just to be clear, the **local** cache (cached by Chrome) was cleared before any of the above were run.

In the case of the **first** and **third**, I ran the test as an administrative user with a session and *was not* served the Super Cache page.  For the **second** and **fourth**, I verified that the server-side cache was populated and requested the page as an anonymous user (and *was* subsequently served the cached page).

In the case of the requests **not** using CloudFlare, *no minification* was present for the **first**, and *only HTML minification* for the **second**.

For the tests **using** CloudFlare, *HTML, CSS, and JavaScript minification* were performed/served automatically, and additionally, resources were combined and required asynchronously when applicable. Also, all static assets were **cached and served** *by the CloudFlare CDN rather than from my EC2 instance*.  The only "*cache distinction*" I make in these two tests was the case of a Super Cache *static version of the dynamic page* being present in-memory or not (present && hit).

*Phew.* 
(It took about as long to cite this verbosely as it did to test).

**I say all of that to ask the following questions:**

1. **Why does Page Speed Online give such funky results?**

   Not accurate, but moreover, the major disparity between using CloudFlare versus not, *completely* counter-intuitive.
2. **You can see above the night-and-day difference between Page Speed Online and the Page Speed Chrome Extension.  Which is a more accurate representation of how Google's algorithm would rank your page in regards to speed?**

   I'm really hopping it's the latter :)
3. **What gives with CloudFlare scoring lower in the both Online and Extension cases without a server-side static cached page?**

   Intuitively, I'd expect that the several performance advantages that CloudFlare offers to at the *very least* be superior to *any* variation of a non-CloudFlare test (minification of JS, CSS, HTML, CDN for *all* static assets *including* images (a hefty portion of the payload), asynchronous loading, etc... **What gives?**

**I applaud you** if you've managed to read and stay attentive this far.  Thanks so much for the time and consideration, and I appreciate any insights anyone can provide in advance!

Just for the sake of transparency, I also posted this to [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Whats-with-the-disparity-between-Page-Speed-Online-and-the-Chrome-Extension-and-in-addition-why-am-I-getting-these-counter-intuitive-results).

Answer (score 5):

Please note: I am answering based on what you've described above only (which, while descriptive, isn't the same as analysing the source(s)).

To your questions above:

1. From [Google Page Speed's own FAQ](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/faq.html):

   > **Some of the suggestions differ from the Page Speed browser extensions. Why?**
   >   Page Speed Online uses a different rendering engine and user agent, which may impact the content being fetched for a site.
   >
   > **How is Page Speed Online different from the Page Speed browser extensions? Which should I use?**
   >   Page Speed Online provides the same analysis as the Page Speed browser extensions for Chrome and Firefox, without needing to install a browser extension.

   Next, you need to understand that CloudFlare (which I use) can/does modify some of the HTTP headers of the elements being requested/responded - expiry headers, etags and the like. Also, [cookies are attached to non-cookied domains](http://www.quora.com/CloudFlare/How-can-I-serve-cookieless-domains-with-Cloudflare).
2. Neither. I wouldn't consider Google's measurement "authoratative" but "representative" only. There's other methods/tests like http://webpagetest.org, http://pingdom.com etc that can give you other geo-specific results.
3. As mentioned above, CloudFlare adds some minor additional payload (cookies, etc) to your entire page package. This **should** be offset by it's CDN capability and other important things like TTFB (Time to First Byte) which have more of a speed impact.

As I mentioned, I use CloudFlare on a number of sites and have optimized them for speed (and Page Speed) to almost 100. The thing to remember is that even with a perfect 100 score, you can still have a slow site. In fact the actual ["speed" metric that Google uses for SEO purposes](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html) is it's [own Toolbar](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/your-sites-performance-in-webmaster.html) (more [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158541)).

If you really want to address speed, you need to address other second-hogs - I recommend http://zoompf.com for picking up on all the other bloat. Lastly, server-speed has a lot to do with things - and not just back-end processing, but connectivity.

I'm not the most technical webby around, but hopefully that helped.

Comment: Great response!  I'll certainly look into the resources you've provided, thanks for the verbosity!  

I'll leave the question open just in case anyone has anything additional to contribute, but I thoroughly appreciate the insight you've provided!